# Merge data of two collections in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

the artist collection consists of the detail of the artist and the art collection consist of the detail of the art by the particular artist. I want to merge both of them . I'm new to mongodb,in SQL I know how to perform the operation, but finding it difficult with mongo

> Artist collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571113f39542ab860bce85d7"),
    "name" : "ajay",
    "email" : "ajay@gmail.com",
    "password" : "d6124b9d34be470dd0387dff9170c825cf8934ed",
    "country" : "in",
    "address" : "mysore",
    "date_of_birth" : {
        "year" : "1992:05:03"
    },
    "type" : "artist"
}
```

> Art Collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57161d2307e2432a49082903"),
    "type" : null,
    "originalname" : null,
    "user_id" : "571113f39542ab860bce85d7",
    "fullPath" : "/code/wd/artifu/backend/uploads/568eec81d2051abe2996f7139d46d143.png",
    "created" : ISODate("2016-04-19T11:57:23.731Z"),
    "data" : {
        "title" : "image",
        "description" : "description",
        "tags" : "forest"
    }
}
```

Comment: Mongo does not support joins, you could use DBRef instead

Comment: You might also wanna check out the `populate` function of [`Mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), if you are allowed to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after going through the documents I was able to merge it, thanks for thoes who commented :)

```
function new(req, res, next) {
    db.arts.findOne({
        _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(req.params._id)
    }, function(err, art) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!art) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: '404 file not found'
            });
        }
        db.users.findOne({
            _id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(art.user_id)
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    status: '404 User not found'
                });
            }
            return res.send({
                user,art
            });

        })
    });
}
```